# finding non empty indices of a pre-allocated vector C++

Tags: c++, vector

Is there any simple way to find the indices of non empty entries of a pre-allocated vector?
one way is to simply loop through the vector. But it is very slow if memory allocated to vector is large and the number of non empty entries is very less.
Below is the example code. In that I have entries for indices `5,9,9,15`, now the task is to identify the `indices` 5,9,15 from the vector x of size `20`. Please suggest some simple way or even a better data structure to do this will be helpful.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    vector <map<int,int>> x(20);
    x[5].insert({ 4,10002 });
    x[9].insert({2,20});
    x[9].insert({ 3, 60 });
    x[15].insert({ 11, 60 });

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If there are overwhelmingly more zero entries than non-zeroes, then I'd just use an `std::map` where all members of the map are nonzero, and the absence of a key (index) indicates that its value is zero.

Comment: Looks like a homework

Comment: But while using unordered map inserting elements into the map will have linear time complexity and find operation will also include cost right ? Also in my case i will have a map in each of the indices, for simplicity i have mentioned it as int above in my code. If duplicate index is there i should insert them in a map. @sammy its not a home work. i need a best data structure that wont incur much cost in all possible way.

Comment: "But ... include cost". Yep. You cannot obtain something for nothing.

Comment: @n.m see the changes to the code and now suggest me .

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to do, but `map<int, map<int, int>>` should fit. Or maybe even `map<pair<int,int>,int>`, depending on what exactly you need.

Comment: @n.m. you are suggesting some thing like this ?                  `map<int, map<int, int>> m;               m[5].insert({ 34, 56 });   m[6].insert({ 4, 76 });    m[4].insert({ 7, 69 });
   m[5].insert({ 334, 456 });`

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I assume for zero entry you mean empty entry (a `map` without elements).

I don't think is possible to remove the iteration cost, but it could be moved to other points of the program (initialization, element insertion, ...) from the point where you want to identify those index.

For example, you can encapsulate two containers in a class: the vector you propose, and a `set<size_t>` with the indexes of the empty entries in the vector. Both should be not directly accessible outside the class (`private`). You must to initialize the set with all indexes in the range vector (iteration here). The insertion of new elements should be through the class interface to remove that index from the set. The removal of new elements too (including removing elements from the map of any entry, to detect when it is going to be empty). To identify the empty entry indexes, well, you have all of them in the set.

As you can see, this approach move the iteration-cost from the point where you want to identify the empty entry indexes to the initialization, adding complexity (and cost) to anywhere else.

Depending of your needs, the containers to use could be different or this approach might be not useful at all.

**UPDATE:** The approach above is right if the problem is looking for empty entry indexes. To solve the problem in the question (identify the non-empty entry indexes), the approach would be:

- using `set<size_t>` to store non-empty indexes,
- nothing to do with the set at initialization.
- when inserting a new element, insert that index in the set
- when removing an element from any of the map in the vector, check if the map become empty to remove the index in that case
- the set will contains the indexes of non-empty entries.

Comment: Instead of using `set` for tracking the `empty entries`, if i use `set` to track the `non empty entries` ie when i insert a element i will put the index in the set it will reduce cost i think. And by this way i dont have to worry about duplicate entries because if i insert same index into the set then only one will be maintained in it.

Comment: You are true. I miss-interpret the question as looking for empty entries instead for non-empty entries (in despite I wrote "non-empty" entries). Then looks more simple. I will edit the answer.